# Reflection axes on Poincaré half-plane model

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, reflection

Working on the Poincaré's half-plane model it is ask to prove that straight lines are reflection axes.
How should I do this?

Comment: In the case of a reflection about a straight line, the straight line is the axis of reflection. (Independently of the axiom of parallelism). What does this have to do with a model?

Comment: I think the point is to prove this reflection preserves the metric. Which it does since the metric tensor does not depend on the horizontal coordinate.

Comment: @Nick Your comment solves the case of vertical lines. But the question posed by the OP deals with any (half)line in the upper plane.

Comment: I see, thanks.  then one constructs an Isometry from any line to the line $[0,\infty]$, by finding a suitable element of $Sl(2,\mathbb{R})$, which maps the end-points at infinity to $0,\infty$.